# okHttp client gives timeout after adding callTimeout() config to it and has moments where the request doesn't reach the host

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

after adding callTimeout() config to the okhttp client I started to get timeouts

```
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .callTimeout(5_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(5_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(5_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
```

I'm not completely sure if having callTimeout configured with the same value as write and read is correct.Is it possible if read and write takes longer to trigger callTimeout()?
Also another weird thing is that there are moments in which the request doesn't even reach the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As after adding the configurations, you are getting this exception, I am suspecting, the requested endpoint needs more time than your configured 5 seconds.

If your requested endpoint is taking more than 5 seconds (5_000 milliseconds) to get a response, you will get a timeout here with this config.

You can use postman to get the response time of your requested endpoint. If it is more than 5 seconds, you can simply configure these values accordingly. Maybe, you can use 30 seconds, instead of 5 Seconds.

I Hope, it helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are moments in which the request doesn't even reach the destination

Comment: Is it after adding the configs?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: Then will you please try increasing the times as I answered?

Answer (score 0):

callTimeOut()

> Sets the default timeout for complete calls. A value of 0 means no
> timeout, otherwise values must be between 1 and [Integer.MAX_VALUE]
> when converted to milliseconds. The call timeout spans the entire
> call: resolving DNS, connecting, writing the request body, server
> processing, and reading the response body. If the call requires
> redirects or retries all must complete within one timeout period. The
> default value is 0 which imposes no timeout.

Correct me if I'm wrong. from what I understand `callTimeOut()` set call timeout spans for the entire call. Eg: you set `callTimeOut = 5s`. if resolving DNS takes 1s, connecting 1s, write 2s, read 2s then you will get TimeOut exception. by default, callTimeOut() is set to no timeout while another default Timeouts is 10s. why do you have to set callTimeOut() to 5s? for me, I have never set callTimeOut before.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible, that you are exceeding your CPU quota. Call timeout is controlled by side-thread (called Watchdog), that is checking in infinite loop if the certain request call timeout was expired ([source code](https://github.com/square/okio/blob/132fde79292f6333c16b3a15571922084e19cf87/okio/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okio/AsyncTimeout.kt#L182)). But when you are creating a large amount of threads and there all are enqueued for CPU the call timeout could be expired while they are waiting in queue, so it doesn't depend on the network. While read and connect timeouts does not depend on the fact of the thread being too long in queue, because these timeouts are managed on OS level.

It also explains why the actual request was not sent - because the request thread was displaced from the CPU axactly after it was registered in the watchdog. And actual request haven't been sent, but the watchdog already decided that the time have passed.

That's why maybe you shouldn't use these kind of timeout for a backend app, especially working in a cloud. It is more relevant for android apps or other clients to use it.